# Sortierung: warum kommt "a" (Kleinbuchstabe) vor "A" (Großbuchstabe)?

Tags: collation, letter-case

Als Programmierer bin ich es (aus der Vergangenheit) gewohnt, dass bei Sortierungen die Großbuchstaben vor den Kleinbuchstaben kommen: In [ASCII haben die lateinischen Großbuchstaben einen kleineren Wert als die kleinen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetische_Sortierung#Computersysteme). Die "echte" Sortierung (und dank [Unicode mit seinem Collation Algorithm](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Collation_Algorithm#Ebene_3:_Gro%C3%9F-_und_Kleinschreibung) auch seit Jahren korrektere Sortierung) sortiert die Kleinbuchstaben meist vor die Großbuchstaben.

Ich suche aber vergeblich nach einer Norm, einer Festlegung, einem Standard, der für (mitunter) mehrere Sprachen (oder nur welche mit lateinischen Buchstaben, oder gar nur Deutsch) eine Sortierung festlegt, die auch darauf eingeht, ob Groß- oder Kleinbuchstaben in einer Sortierung zuerst kommen. Und zwar unabhängig von der IT, in der sich seit 1990 dank Unicode vieles in dieser Hinsicht standardisiert hat. In der Zeit davor muss es ja auch Fälle gegeben haben, bei denen man sich mal grundlegend einigen musste, ob die Klein- vor den Großbuchstaben kommen oder nicht.

Dass es unterschiedliche Sortierregeln gibt, liegt auf der Hand:

- in einem Telefonbuch bin ich erstmal am Nachnamen interessiert ("*Mustermann, Max*")
- in einem Wörterbuch soll unabhängig von Groß-/Kleinschreibung sortiert werden ("*Form*", "*formlos*")
- bei Titeln sollen häufig am Anfang stehende Artikel bei der Sortierung erst sehr spät berücksichtigt werden ("*Untergang, der*")

Unter Microsoft *Windows* habe ich mit deutscher Sprache z.B. die Wahl zwischen den Sortiermethoden "Wörterbuch" und "Telefonbuch (DIN)".

Aber wo ist abseits von der Digitalwelt definiert, dass "a" eigentlich vor "A" kommt? Auch in anderen Sprachen (z.B. Ungarisch). Gibt es Beispiele, an denen das deutlich wird? Ich könnte auch fragen, wo festgelegt ist, in welcher Reihenfolge das Alphabet der deutschen Sprache stehen muss - warum wir überhaupt mindestens die jetzigen beiden Sortierungen haben. Nur halt mit dem Zusatz, in welcher Reihenfolge Groß- gegenüber Kleinbuchstaben stehen.

Comment: Mir ist nicht klar, inwiefern das eine Frage zur deutschen Sprache ist. Daher halte ich die Frage hier für off-topic. Kannst du das genauer herausarbeiten?

Comment: Wüsste nicht, welche passendere Stelle dafür geeignet ist. Es ist nahezu wie die Frage, wo festgelegt ist, dass das Alphabet in der jetzigen Reihenfolge steht - alle verwenden es so, irgendwie ist es historisch gewachsen, aber gibt es auch nur eine Referenz?

Comment: Ohne ein Anwendungsfeld wirst du auf alle möglichen Sortierungen stoßen.

Comment: ...was ich ja bereits schrieb. Und nach etwas Grundlegendem fragte, unabhängig vom Kontext.

Comment: Das verstehe ich nicht so richtig. Du sagst, dass dir bewusst ist, dass die gesuchte Regel notwendigerweise kontextabhängig ist, und fragst dann nach einer kontextfreien Regel. Verstehe ich das so richtig?

Comment: Oder nach einer Basis, von der dann je nach Kontext abgewichen wird (am naheliegensten, da die meisten Sortierungen weiterhin A > B > C... nutzen, statt dass alle Varianten zufällig große Teile gemein haben).

Answer (score 1):

*Selbstverständlich* gibt es dafür in Deutschland eine DIN-Norm (besser gesagt, sogar 2):

- DIN 5007, Ordnen von Schriftzeichenfolgen
- DIN 31638, Bibliographische Ordnungsregeln

Außer den eher trivialen Regeln, wie Groß- und Kleinschreibung zu sortieren ist, befassen sich diese Normen mit der Sortierung von Umlauten und Sonderzeichen.

Diese DIN-Normen sind schon ziemlich alt - 5007 stammt aus 1928 und befasst sich hauptsächlich mit der Sortierung von Eigennamen (z.B. für Telefonbücher), während 31638 sich auf allgemeinere Anwendungsfälle konzentriert (dort findest du auch Antwort auf deine Frage, ob "a" vor oder nach "A" kommen soll).

Es mag interessant sein, dass es für die deutsche Sprache keine allgemeinen Regeln gibt: Umlaute in Namen werden z.B. in österreichischen und deutschen Telefonbüchern traditionell unterschiedlich einsortiert (AT sortiert den Umlaut grundsätzlich hinter seinem Basisvokal, DE sortiert den Umlaut wie seinen Basisvokal ein). Um die ganze Sache noch ein wenig komplizierter zu machen, sortiert das  österreichische Telefonbuch sein Ortsverzeichnis auch nach anderen Regeln als sein Namensverzeichnis.

Sortierung ist überhaupt ein weites Feld: Je nach Anwendungsfeld gibt es alles, was man sich vorstellen kann: Es gibt z.B. Wörterbücher, die Wörter nicht in der Schreibrichtung, sondern engegengesetzt (rückwärts) sortieren - Das ist z.B. für Reimwörterbücher sinnvoll. Daraus ergibt sich, dass deine Frage praktisch nicht beantwortet werden kann: Die Sortierreihenfolge ist nicht etwa statisch festgelegt, sondern ergibt sich (logischerweise) aus der Anwendung. Man sortiert so, dass das was man sucht, am schnellsten gefunden werden kann.

Wenn deine Frage sich auf die reine alphabetische Reihenfolge (A-Z) konzentriert, verschwindet die Antwort schnell im Nebel der Geschichte: Das wahrscheinlich erste alphabetisch sortierte Wörterbuch (nicht in Deutsch, sondern Latein) stammt aus der Zeit vor Christi Geburt und wurde vom Hauslehrer Julius Caesars geschrieben.

Und abschließend: Deine Annahme, dass Kleinbuchstaben vor Großbuchstaben (oder andersrum) einzuordnen wären, ist eher mutig, wenn nicht gar falsch: Grundsätzlich gibt es für jede Anwendung passende Regeln, wenn Groß- und Kleinschreibung für den Anwendungsfall nicht relevant sind, werden sie u.U. einfach ignoriert (siehe Telefonbuch). Kurz gesagt: Es gibt keine solche Regel, ausser sie wäre für den Anwendungsfall praktisch.

Comment: "_Je nach Anwendungsfeld_" ist wiederum einem Programmierer _selbstverständlich_. Schade, dass die DINs (oder gar deren relevante Teile) nicht verlinkt sind. Nein, Sortierung hat bei weitem nicht nur mit Finden zu tun. Praktischer Anwendungsfall Wörterbuch: soll die Konjunktion [mal](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mal#Konjunktion) vor oder nach dem Substantiv [Mal](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mal#Substantiv,_n) eingeordnet werden? In meinem kommt das kleine vor dem großen.

Comment: Zur Herkunft des Alphabets, bzw. seiner Sortierung: die ist im Großen und Ganzen vom lateinischen Alphabet, das sich (mit einem Umweg über die Etrusker) vom griechischen Alphabet ableitet, das wiederum vom phönizischen Alphabet abstammt. Dazu kommt, daß Minuskeln lange Zeit keine Rolle spielten (siehe Capitalis Monumentalis, Capitalis Rustica und Capitalis Quadrata, ebenso die Ältere Römische Kursive). Die ersten Minuskelschriften sind die Jüngere Römische Kursive, die ab dem 4. Jhdt. verwendet wird und die daraus entstehende Halbunziale (ab ca. 5. Jhdt).

Comment: @AmigoJack Selbstverständlich sortiert man nur, damit man besser findet - auch in einem Wörterbuch. Ich wüsste nicht, warum Wörterbücher sonst sortiert sein sollten. Das ist eben der Hauptaspekt vom Sortieren.

Comment: *Gute* Wörterbücher haben übrigens i.A. einen Anhang, der genau erklärt, wie die Einträge sortiert sind (z.B. ob "mal" vor "Mal" kommt). Alleine das zeigt schon, dass es z.B. für Wörterbücher keinen Standard gibt.

Comment: Sortierungen können z.B. auch auf phonetische oder optische Ähnlichkeiten abzielen - das kann man nur abstrakt als "finden" bezeichnen. Noch dazu gibt es gemischte Alphabete (nicht separat ABC... und abc..., sondern Aa Bb Cc... oder halt doch vielleicht aA bB cC...).

Comment: @AmigoJack Selbst nach phonetischen und optischen Ähnlichkeiten muss man nur sortieren, wenn man sie wiederfinden will (oder, wenn einem wirklich sehr, sehr langweilig ist) - ich verstehe deine Sturheit hier isrgendwie nicht.

Comment: "_Sturheit_"... Trotz Hinweis nicht eine [Verlinkung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetische_Sortierung#Deutschland) zu setzen wirkt auf mich ebenso. Bei Ähnlichkeitssortierungen will man nicht direkt finden, sondern einschätzen, wie nahe sich zwei Zeichen stehen. Zugegeben: das ist vielleicht eher eine Einordnung statt Sortierung: `l` und `L` sind sich optisch weniger ähnlich als z.B. `I` oder `1`. Nenn ich da wirklich Anwendungsgebiete fernab der Vorstellungskraft?